# Flutter, content padding for TextFormField not working correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following input text form field I'm trying to have some space better the input and text or padding

```
InputDecoration buildInputDecoration(
    String hintText, String lableText, double fontSize) {
  return InputDecoration(
    //hintText: hintText,
    labelText: lableText,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: fontSize,
    ),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 55.0),
  );
}

final usernameField = Container(
        child: TextFormField(
      //textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
      autofocus: false,
      validator: validateEmail,
      onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
      decoration: buildInputDecoration('Confirm password', 'Email', 16),
    ));
```

As you can see here it looks good
[image]

but when I input text the input text is all the way to the top and not part of the line or border
[image]

How can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

The `padding` will work indeed. But in order to have `0 padding` on a `TextField`, consider adding the `dense` property as following

```
InputDecoration(
  // ...
  isDense: true,
),
```

Comment: Just reverse the `padding` value like this `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0)`

Comment: yea that works, how to change the font size when the text filed is selected

Comment: Use a boolean variable and change it's value whenever your TextField change focus. Consequently, adjust the font size of your TextField depending on your variable